# How to use systemd WatchDog to allow alive pings from a child process?

Tags: systemd, watchdog

I've configured a bash script that pipes multiple processes to run as a service. This works fine but I now want to use `WatchdogSec` to monitor if the state is still ok and if not to restart all child processes.

application-C has the logic to notify based on the `WATCHDOG_USEC` envvar. If the application is invoked this works fine but it doesn't when part of the script and being the last process

The logic is more or less, if application-C didn't receive certain data it is considered unhealthy thus everything should be killed and restarted.

Currently, the service daemon is restarting all processes every 30 seconds and the signaling doesn't seem to work from the process when part of a script.

Likely the watchdog only accepts pings from the bash shell process.

Can I get this to work somehow?

```
[Unit]
Description=My script
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/src/
ExecStart=/bin/bash myscript.sh
WatchdogSec=30s
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Script:

```
application-a | application-b |application-c
```